# Locating the value attribute for the fast search text box on EDGAR website

Tags: html

I'm writing code for a EDGAR database puller in Visual Studio, however I'm stuck on trying to isolate/locate the "value" attribute for the text element under the 'fast-search' function (under the label: Ticker or CIK). the website url is: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

I'm learning HTML self-taught.

This is the HTML code that is represented when viewed through the "inspect element" for the txt box:

```
label class="overlabel" style="visibility: visible;" for="cik">Ticker or CIK/label>
input name="CIK" title="Ticker or CIK" id="cik" type="text" size="27" alt="Ticker or CIK"
```

Comment: Hi, please add some code and show us your effort for solving this issue

Comment: web_MyBrowser.Document.GetElementById("cik").SetAttribute("value", txt_StockTicker.Text);

Comment: I'm trying to get the value/input attribute for the box, but I'm unable to locate it within the element - - the next step would be to pass a local variable to place into the box

Comment: document.getElementById("cik").value = "local_variable_place_into_box"